# how to create sprite with css

Tags: html, css, sprite

[image]

In above picture when I hover to blog it shows
[image]

and when I hover to twitter it shows
[image]

[Live example of website](http://www.chaudharygroup.com/)

Comment: Ya so? What's the question?

Comment: looks like the developer is changing the position of the image based on the hover section dynamically. you need javascript or its libraries to do this. I think so.

Comment: @Mr.Alien See question above: how to create sprite with css?

Comment: @Mr_Green someone said to me it is only css.

Comment: @C-Link There are 100's of articles out there, you need to search and learn

Comment: I didn't find like this

Comment: why minus votes ?  please mention

Comment: @C-Link Not the downvoter but wait I'll [search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=css+sprite+hover&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) for you...

Comment: Well such a question with this reputation.!!! well this can also be done using JavaScript.

Comment: ya it is possible just using css. my assumption was wrong. :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien did you find like this?

Comment: @C-Link There are many many available, just apply some logics

Comment: @Mr.Alien Not like this I tried much but couldn't, please could you provide your brief answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is setting the space between the images and setting the values of the `background-position` in CSS. Below is the actual sprite of the aforementioned website.

http://www.chaudharygroup.com/templates/cg/images/social-network-icons.jpg

And then, you can set the width of the anchor or list item in CSS on `:hover`.

### Update

Seems like easier said than done, but works as expected. Below are the lines of code in CSS.

```
ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li a {
    background: transparent url('sprite-images.jpg');
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
ul li:hover {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 150px;
}
/** Set Width on mouseover. Not only anchor tags has the privilege to
    use the :hover nowadays. **/
ul li:hover a {
    width: 150px;
}

/** These codes below that SOers are trying to tell you. **/
ul li.b a {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
ul li.t a {
    background-position: -29px 0;
}
ul li.f a {
    background-position: -58px 0;
}
ul li.y a {
    background-position: -90px 0;
}
ul li.b:hover a {
    background-position: -173px 0;
}
ul li.t:hover a {
    background-position: -315px 0;
}
ul li.f:hover a {
    background-position: -477px 0;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/jlratwil/fBDnN/17/

Comment: Oh! this means all in one picture\ thanks. but why my question goes minus votes

Comment: I did it but confused doing it hover. please explain your answer briefly

Comment: I'll re-accept your answer after my problem is solved.

Comment: I was just confusing with li:hover{position: absolute;} method which i din't. now I understood how this works?